# if the database is empty, code will not work

Tags: database, laravel, function, exists

if the database does not contain an entry, the code will not work. If an entry exists, the code works. Does anyone know why the code only works if there is already an entry in the database?

I get the timeout error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

_

with the code I create the user, then his profile in connection with the inviting URL. A unique code with a length of 7 characters is created, which is the individual invitation URL. 
I need the loop because it has to be checked if the code has ever been generated. Or is there a better solution?

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    if($data['gender'])

    {
        $avatar = 'defaults\avatars\male.jpg';
    }

    else

    {
        $avatar = 'defaults\avatars\female.jpg';
    }

    if (array_key_exists('team_id', $data) && $data['team_id']){
        $team = $data['team_id'];
    }else{
       $team = Null;
    }

    if (isset($data['invited_id']) && $data['invited_id']){
        $invited_from = $data['invited_id'];
    }else{
        $invited_from = Null;
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'team_id' => $team,
        'invited_from_id' => $invited_from,
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'slug' => str_slug($data['username']),
        'avatar' => $avatar,
        'active' => false,
        'activation_token' => str_random(255)
    ]);

    $user->profile()->save(new Profile());

    while (true) {
        $randomstring = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 7);
        if (Invite::where('url','!=', $randomstring)->exists()) {
            Invite::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'url' => $randomstring
            ]);
            break;
        }
    }

    //store notify for user in database
    $usern = User::find($invited_from);

    if($usern) {
        User::find($usern->id)->notify(new NotifyInvite($user));
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: can you please show the error that you get?

Comment: i get the timeout error, i add it to my question

Comment: Just an FYI, you shouldn't need to re-find the user to notify them as you already have them in the `$usern` variable i.e. `$usern->notify(new NotifyInvite($user))` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your database, the problem is that you never break out of your loop if the condition is not satisfied. So `while(true)` will run forever. You need to add a default case to your condition, which will exit the loop.

Comment: how can i add a default case?

Comment: You need to share more on what you are trying to achieve here. As a default you should have `break;` out of your if condition in order to terminate the loop even if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: so instead of your way of generating random 7 chars you can use the `str_random(7)` helper function. And also, try to debug why your condition returns false even in an empty database. I tried your condition on one of my tables, and it returns true. So once it returns true based on your code it should break out of the while loop.

Comment: If the database is empty, this code `Invite::where('url','!=', $randomstring)->exists()`  returns false. Why? 
I do not understand it, it should generate a new code until a non-existent code was generated.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, you need to debug it. I tried the same condition on one of my tables, and it returns true as it should.

Comment: how can i debug it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183850/discussion-between-nakov-and-slickness).